# Is it possible to add selector text to a By object

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am wondering if it is possible to add selector text to an existing By object.

That is, suppose I have a popup with a class name ".popup".  But then I want to be a little more specific as the webapp is utilized.  Now, our popup has an added class name ".cart". My new selector wants to be ".popup.cart".  Here is what I have. Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?  (I'm coding in C#, but it can be relevant to any language.)

```
By selector= By.CssSelector("div.popup");
selector = By.CssSelector(
    selector.ToString().Remove(0, selector.ToString().LastIndexOf(":") + 1) 
    + ".cart");
```

What is going on above, selector becomes "div.popup".
selector.ToString() returns "By.CssSelector: div.popup"
So I remove all text from the beginning to the last ":" and add the remaining text to ".cart".
selector then becomes "div.popup.cart", which is what I want.

The problem comes when I try to combine any selectors that have been "ByChained."  The ToString() method will return `By.Chained([By.CssSelector: .popup, By.CssSelector: .title])`

If it helps, I am also Sizzle. So, if there's a JQuery way to do this, I'm open.

Comment: From a quick look at the C# and java documentation, the answer is no.  Additionally, `ByChained` doesn't look for one object that matches all selectors, it looks for an object that matches selector1, then for an object under selector1 that matches selector2.

Comment: That's what I'm seeing too. I'm half up to taking the By.cs file and modifying it to make the text visible. But, for now, I'm unrolling the ToString() return text.

Answer (score 1):

Put the "div.popup" in a string say "str" like this:-

`String str = div.popup`

Then you can append ".cart" to the string, make it "div.popup.cart", and use the **cssSelector** as:

`By selector= By.cssSelector(str+".cart");`

**Note:- Above is a java code.**

Comment: That would be good, but the selector is created in another class and method. I don't have access to the original string.

Comment: @Machtyn : You can put all the locators(xpath/id/etc.) in one class file say: **"Locators.java"** and they can be represented like this: `public static String xyz = "//div[.='hello']";` Then you can access them from your code in a different class as `driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locators.xyz))` **(Note:- 'xyz' is a public variable, so can be accessed outside the class using class name)**

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above, I'm basically solving this by unrolling the By.CssSelector().ToString() output and/or the ByChained().ToString() output.  There are some caveats. Mainly that the last selector in a ByChained() must be of type By.CssSelector (since I'm adding a JQuery pseudo class):

```
private static By AddPseudoFunction(By selector, string pseudoFunc)
{
  string type = selector.GetType().ToString();
  string selectorValue = selector.ToString();

  if (type.Contains("Chained"))
  {
    selectorValue = selectorValue.Remove(0, selector.ToString().IndexOf("[") + 1);
    int start = selectorValue.LastIndexOf("]");
    int delta = selectorValue.Length - start;
    selectorValue = selectorValue.Remove(start, delta);
  }
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (string s in selectorValue.Split(','))
  {
    builder.Append(" ");
    builder.Append(s.ToString().Remove(0, s.ToString().LastIndexOf(":") + 2));
  }
  selectorValue = builder.ToString().TrimStart(' ') + pseudoFunc;

  return new ByJQuery.ByJQuerySelector(selectorValue, true);
}
```

Of course, if you want to make this so that it will return a By.CssSelector, just replace the return with:

```
return By.CssSelector(selctorValue + addSelector);
```

Where addSelector would be a valid CSS Selector value (like what I describe in the question).

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it relies on parsing a value with no documented behavior that could change at any time. The far better approach would be to build the selector string. If your wrapper library doesn't allow you to get that string, it's a bug in the wrapper library's design.